# Using quotes on a sudo encapsulated sed command already using quotes

Tags: json, linux, shell, sed, sudo

I have a shell script, where I want to change the following text in a JSON file:

```
"foo-bar": true
```

to this:

```
"foo-bar": false
```

I want to do this by using the `sed` command.  However, the JSON script resides in my `/etc` directory.  Therefore, I have to encapsulate the whole command in a `sudo sh -c` command.

Here was my first attempt:

```
sudo sh -c "sed -e 's/"foo-bar": true/"foo-bar": false/' /etc/sample.json > /etc/sample2.json"
```

I thought the `:` was causing a problem so I escaped them, but that didn't help:

```
sudo sh -c "sed -e 's/"foo-bar"\: true/"foo-bar"\: false/' /etc/sample.json > /etc/sample2.json"
```

Still didn't work.  So, I tried the double-quotes which someone suggested on a similar post on Stackoverflow:

```
sudo sh -c "sed -e 's/""foo-bar""\: true/""foo-bar""\: false/' /etc/sample.json > /etc/sample2.json"
```

But to no avail.

Now, I'm really stumped.  Because it is an encapsulated sudo command, I need the extra quotes around the entire command and I believe this is what is causing the problem.  But how can I get around it?

Comment: how about escaping the inner double quotes?

Comment: Handling JSON with `sed` is not a terribly good idea. Can you show a sample of the JSON you're trying to edit? This is probably trivial with `jq`.

Comment: Here is a sample of the JSON:
    "preallocation": 1,
    "prefetch-enabled": 1,
    "queue-stalled-enabled": true,
    "queue-stalled-minutes": 30,
    "ratio-limit": 2,
    "ratio-limit-enabled": false,
    "rename-partial-files": true,

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
echo sed -e 's/"foo-bar": true/"foo-bar": false' /etc/sample/sjon >/etc/sample2.json' | sudo sh
```

In other words, build the command locally then let sh(1) pick up the command from stdin.